# New iTunes App installation

Tags: iphone, itunes, upgrade, ios

After updating my iTunes to the new 12.2.0.145 I can no longer manage the apps on my iPhone 6+ from iTunes.  The apps show up and there is the install/uninstall buttons beside them, but they are grayed out and unavailable.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Your iTunes is now incompatible with your iOS version. Either downgrade iTubes or upgrade iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Did you update to iOS 8.4 yet?
If not, now would be the time.

In iTunes - sync; backup; update.

If you're already on 8.4, then sync; backup; restore.

Comment: Normally that would fix the issue, and it would have been  of my list if my phone were not cydia enabled.  8.4 isn't compatible so I am still running 8.1.2

Comment: That would tell me it's not the iTunes update that's broken then, it's the jailbreak. I'd look to cydia for a fix.